# How to remove text from textflow in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, textflow

I'm new to javafx and am trying to display large amount of text in textflow. It displays fine, but I just cannot figure out how to delete the text.

So what I'm trying to do is delete all Text nodes from textFlow like so

```
textFlow.getChildren().removeAll();
```

But when I do this and add something to textFlow, it shows after the text that was already displayed there. I would like the text that was there removed and show the added text from the beginning of the textflow.

I guess I have to somehow rerender the view of textflow, but I don't know how. So how do I delete everything and add Text anew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`removeAll(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#removeAll-E...-) will remove all the values you pass as parameters: in your case there are none, so it doesn't remove anything. Use

```
textFlow.getChildren().clear();
```